# Freezing output screen in VSCode after entering -1

Tags: vector, visual-studio-code, stl, c++17, unordered-set

The program is about LONGEST SUBSEQUENCE. I tried to give input until -1 is occurred but the output console is getting hanged after I enter -1. I tried running it on online compilers too...but still no solution.

[Here is the output screenshot in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJAAJ.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    unordered_set<int> s;
    int count, res = 0;
    cout << "Enter the elements of the array: ";
    while (1)
    {
        cin >> count;
        if (count == -1)
            break;
        v.push_back(count);
        s.insert(count);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i != v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (s.find(v.at(i) - 1) != s.end())
        {
            count = 1;
            while (s.find(v[i] + 1) != s.end())
                count++;
            res = max(res, count);
        }
    }

    cout << res;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled your code in two of my compiler and changed its header files it works fine for me

PS I changed `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` header file with `#include<vector>` and `#include <unordered_set>`. Moreover I added `{ }` currly braces in if statement because sometimes compilers as well as editors gets confuse if we dont use currly braces with loops and conditional statement.

Here is your code

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    unordered_set<int> s;
    int count, res = 0;
    cout << "Enter the elements of the array: ";
    while (1)
    {
        cin >> count;
        if (count == -1)
        {
            break;
            v.push_back(count);
            s.insert(count);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i != v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (s.find(v.at(i) - 1) != s.end())
        {
            count = 1;
            while (s.find(v[i] + 1) != s.end())
                count++;
            res = max(res, count);
        }
    }

    cout << res;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried running your code in my compiler but the problm is that "v.push_back(count) and s.insert(count)" are not inside the "if" block. The "if" block only contains "break" statement. After these changes, if I run the code, the problem is still not solved.